# r convert nested dataframe to xts

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested, xts

I am trying to secure proper convert from a dataframe (with nested dataframes & lists) into xts. I know that the best startpoint is to use a matrix as a base for creating an xts, but I am trying to simulate how I get the original downloaded data.

My question: If I need to use the base setup with nested dataframes and list, what steps other than in the below script, do I need to secure to get the data into xts?

Below you find my code. Note that it works to get the xts produced if uncomment complete section "3."

```
# 1.creates the "top-level" df
date <- c("2016-10-10 21:32:00", "2016-10-10 21:33:00") # vector for creating the df
volume <- c(1,2) # vector for creating the df
df2 <- data.frame(date = date, volume = volume) # creating the df

# 2.change class of 2 columns
df2$date <- as.POSIXct(df2$date) #change from character to POSIX
df2$volume <- as.numeric(df2$volume) #change from character to numeric

# 3.create openPrices (set: base/bid/ask) < - Potential problem for creating xts
df2$openPrice <- data.frame(no2 = c(1,2)) # creating a nested df with 2 temp column/values.
df2$openPrice$bid <- list(1.1, 1.2) # creating a list within the nested df
df2$openPrice$ask <- list(2.2, 2.3) # creating a list within the nested df
df2$openPrice$no2 <- NULL # remove the 2 temp column/values

# 4.create an xts(myxts1), based on a dataframe (df2) with nested dataframes and lists.
myxts1 <- xts(df2[,-1],order.by = df2$date)
```

! Note. The result needs to be stripped off from nested, since it is 
the nested that provokes problem for the step of creating the xts.

Comment: `df2 <- purrr::map_df(cbind(df2[,1:2], df2[,3]), unlist) ; xts::xts(df2[,-1], order.by = df2$date)`

Comment: Hi. Your suggestions gives: 
Error in `[.data.frame`(df2, , 3) : undefined columns selected